# Why am I getting code 400 in this Post Request?

Tags: vb.net, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to use the MS Graph API to send messages in a Microsoft Teams chat .

With this C# code everything works fine:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/chats/19:meeting_OGFlZjhjYjgtYWFlOS00NjYzLThmMjUtNzYwNTQ5MjBiYzlh@thread.v2/messages");
    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer AccessTOKEN");
    var content = new StringContent("{\"body\":{\"content\":\"teste\"}}", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    request.Content = content;
    var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    Console.WriteLine(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
}
```

But I need to implement this in a vb.net project, so I wrote the below code:

```
Public Async Sub Callapi()

    Try

        Dim client = New HttpClient()
        Dim request = New HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/chats/19:meeting_OGFlZjhjYjgtYWFlOS00NjYzLThmMjUtNzYwNTQ5MjBiYzlh@thread.v2/messages")
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer Accesstoken")
        Dim content = New StringContent("{""body"":{""content"":""teste""}}", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
        request.Content = content
        Dim response = Await client.SendAsync(request)
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
        Console.WriteLine(Await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync())

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

But it always returns me the Bad Request 400 code. Can anyone please help me find the error?

So I wrote the below code:

```
Public Async Sub Callapi()

    Try

        Dim client = New HttpClient()
        Dim request = New HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/chats/19:meeting_OGFlZjhjYjgtYWFlOS00NjYzLThmMjUtNzYwNTQ5MjBiYzlh@thread.v2/messages")
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer Accesstoken")
        Dim content = New StringContent("{""body"":{""content"":""teste""}}", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
        request.Content = content
        Dim response = Await client.SendAsync(request)
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
        Console.WriteLine(Await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync())

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Stop swallowing the exception. Any information that might help you is lost because you don't check ex.Message. If the C# code didn't need a try/catch, why add one to VB?